# Printing 2d array with markers set by coordinates on Java

Tags: java

I have a basic question, which is literally driving me mad.
I have a method which is gets a list of some objects as a parameter. Every object has a pair of ints (for x and y coordinates respectivly).
The goal is: print the 2d array with markers set for every object in the list at given coordinates, like example below (m-is a marker; array size is h:2, w:5). Array width and high must stay intact.

```
m....
...m.
```

Here's one of solutions I've come to. Its main issue that array width is multiplied with the amount of objects in the parameter list.

Assumption: Array is a char array and predefined. Named 't'.

```
public void printArray (ArrayList<Marker> marker) {
    for (int h=0;h<t.length;h++) {
        for (int w=0;w<t[h].length;w++) {
            for (Marker m: marker) {
                if (h==m.getY() && w==m.getX()) {
                    System.out.print('m');
                } else {
                    System.out.print('.');
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
```

Please, give me a clue how to fight this.
Thanks.

Comment: `t` is a field in the object of which `printArray` is a member function?

Comment: To begin with a) `lenght` should be `length` in your for loops, b) what does your current output look like? c) Could you show us how does "t" look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite obvious why this happens of course: for each coordinate you print a character for each marker. This is solved by getting rid of the loops on `h` and `w`.

This can for example be done something like this:

```
public void printArray (ArrayList<Marker> marker) {

    // Create an array of chars, and make sure all values are set to '.'
    boolean[][] array = new char[t.length][t[h].length];
    for (int h=0; h < t.length; h++) {
        for (int w=0; w < t[h].length; w++) {
            array[h][w] = '.';
        }
    }

    // For each marker, set the value in the array at the marker's position to m
    for (Marker m: marker) {
        array[m.getY()][m.getX()] = 'm';
    }

    // Print the array
    for (int h=0; h<t.length; h++) {
        for (int w=0; w<t[h].length; w++) {
            System.out.print(array[h][w]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Probably this is not the optimal solution, because there is a lot of looping. I don't know if java has a better method for initializing the array values, for example.

Comment: Great! It worked, thank you very much. I wonder if ither solution exists which allow to skip array initialization step but do it on the 'print' phase.

Comment: @bucky yes, you should use a boolean array, as Xema suggests. You don't need to initialize the arrays then, because the default value of booleans is false. I think that method is better anyway. The only reason I did not upvote it, is because he doesn't use braces on the `else`.

Comment: Hmmm, I've checked Xema's solution, for me it's looks like the same the only diferrence is array is boolean and initializaed by boolean values and maybe bit more complicated. Anyway it is also make sense. Thank you all, guys!

Comment: That's right, but there you can skip array initialization, even though his example does do it explicitly, as booleans don't are false by default. I also believe his method is better, as it allows for easier modification of what precisely to print. You might even want to put creation of the boolean array in a different function so it can be reused.

Answer (score 0):

You should not print a character for *every* Marker in the innermost loop; instead, use that loop to determine what character is to be printed at the current (h,w) location, and then *after* the Marker loop, print the appropriate character.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well what you want to do, an idea would be to instantiate an array of boolean, representing wether there is at least an object with the cell's coordinates. And then you loop throw the boolean array, and print, as you did, "m" if true, "." if false.

Here is an example (haven't tried it yet, though)

Instantiate the array :

```
boolean[][] boolTab = new boolean[2][5];
for (boolean[] row : boolTab){
     Arrays.fill(row,false);
}
```

Fill this array whenever there is an object :

```
for (Marker m: marker) {
    boolTab[m.getY()][m.getX()] = 'm';
}
```

Printing the array :

```
for (int h=0;h<2;h++) {
    for (int w=0;w<5;w++) {
        if (boolTab[h][w]){
           System.out.print('m');
        }
        else System.out.print('.');
    }
    System.out.print('\n');
}
```

I've kept it simple, without considering your intial dimension of your array. But you can adapt this code above quite easily I think.

EDIT : some improvement edits suggested by Oebele.

EDIT 2 : misusage of the fill function, correcting it.

Comment: you can greatly simplify the second bit by removing the outer loops

Comment: And PLEASE use braces around the if and else when printing. Much better for readability and thus less prone to making mistakes.

Comment: True enough, this is just a convention with myself i get used to.

Comment: You should not get used to this style, but to using braces. You won't believe the problems I have seen caused by it.

Comment: It should be Arrays.fill, not Array. Also: are you sure it works with 2D arrays? If so, do you mind if I change my answer to use this as well (credited of course)

Comment: Well, after some investigations, it seems not. But we can still use the function into the rows of the array.

Comment: You can actually skip the entire fill bit, as booleans are false by default.